# Confusion on KeyListeners

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm trying to get keyboard input and set Boolean values depending on what buttons are pressed. I make an instance of this class in one of my player class to update position, here's my code:

```
public class Keyboard extends KeyAdapter implements KeyListener
{
boolean downClick, upClick, leftClick, rightClick = false;

public Keyboard()
{
    Game.getGame().getFrame().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter())
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) downClick = true;
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) upClick = true;
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) leftClick = true;
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) rightClick = true;
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) downClick = false;
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) upClick = false;
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) leftClick = false;
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) rightClick = false;
}

public boolean isDownClick() 
{
    return downClick;
}

public boolean isUpClick() 
{
    return upClick;
}

public boolean isLeftClick() 
{
    return leftClick;
}

public boolean isRightClick() 
{
    return rightClick;
}

}
```

I'm pretty much positive `Game.getGame().getFrame().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter())` is incorrect. Just to clarify `Game.getGame().getFrame()` is just getting my JFrame. What does addKeyListener want as a parameter? And is that the only problem in my code because the input is not moving my on screen component. The component code is efficent and works fine. There's no bugs there just in this one class.

Comment: You made `Keyboard extends KeyAdapter` and want that your `keyPressed` method is used. Therefore, you need to pass yourself as parameter (=`this`) instead of some other key adapter. That should work to some degree, see MadProgrammers answer.

Comment: Exactly what zapl said. Right now, whenever a key is pressed, it's going straight to an empty `KeyAdapter`. See my answer.

Comment: But see MadProgrammer's answer for the more robust and stable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `KeyListener` for this kind of job, use the key bindings API, it provides better control over the focus level required to generate key events.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details...

The problem is multi leveled...

First, `KeyListener` will only raise events on components it is registered to if that component is focusable AND has focus.

Second, between the user and the actualy frame, there are a number of layers...

[image]

...any of these could be stealing focus from the frame and preventing events from reaching it...

Answer (score 1):

You're adding an empty `KeyAdapter` to the frame. Try `Game.getGame().getFrame().addKeyListener(this)` instead. That way, your methods will actually be called instead of a random KeyAdapter's methods.

And here's the updated code:

```
public class Keyboard implements KeyListener { // A KeyAdapter already implements a key listener. You don't need both...
    boolean downClick = false;
    boolean upClick = false;
    boolean leftClick = false;
    boolean rightClick = false;
    // Unlike other languages, Java makes you define each variable by itself. Even though the previous would have worked, (by default Java Booleans are false), this is a nicer way to put it and follows conventions for what you're wanting to do.

    public Keyboard() {
        Game.getGame().getFrame().addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) downClick = true;
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) upClick = true;
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) leftClick = true;
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) rightClick = true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) downClick = false;
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) upClick = false;
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) leftClick = false;
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) rightClick = false;
    }

    public boolean isDownClick() {
        return downClick;
    }

    public boolean isUpClick() {
        return upClick;
    }

    public boolean isLeftClick() {
        return leftClick;
    }

    public boolean isRightClick() {
        return rightClick;
    }
}
```